# Classic ASP: RecordSet Field giving no value

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript, field, ado, recordset

I'm not really an ASP developer, so a little bit lost.

I have the following data access code:

```
sSQL = "SELECT answer_id, company_name, old_access_company_name, answer, flag_asker_notified FROM Q01_ask_sheiiba_answer_company2 WHERE question_id="& sQuestion_id &" ORDER BY answer_id"
rs.open sSQL, conn  
DO WHILE NOT rs.EOF
    Response.Write(rs.Fields("answer"))
    rs.MoveNext
LOOP
```

I have tested that the sql query is built properly by outputting it to the response before it is called. It produces the following query:

```
SELECT answer_id, company_name, old_access_company_name, answer, flag_asker_notified 
FROM Q01_ask_sheiiba_answer_company2 
WHERE question_id=988 
ORDER BY answer_id
```

When I copy that exact query to sql management studio and run it I get the expected results of 5 rows and each row containing data in every cell, BUT, when I run it through the above code, I get the same 5 rows with the same cell data, EXCEPT for the `answer` column, which is empty!

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What data type is the 'answer' column? I bet it's either a varchar/nvachar with > 8000 chars, or a text/ntext. What is your connection -- ODBC or OLEDB (SQLOLEDB)?

Comment: @webaware Yes it's `text` and the connection is set as follows `SET conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")` `conn.open "ODBC-Datasource-Name"`

Comment: @webaware So does that mean anything to you? Is there a known issue and - more importantly - a solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two things you might want to try:

Put your text field at the end of the query.  For example:

SELECT answer_id, company_name, old_access_company_name, flag_asker_notified, answer

If this doesn't give you the results, you might want to try:

```
WHILE NOT rs.EOF
theanswer=rs("answer")
Response.Write(theanswer)
rs.movenext
wend
```

Text and Memo fields can play a little havoc with ASP.

**EDIT**: Another thing that you can try is:

```
rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
```

or

```
rs.CursorLocation = 3
```

Comment: I had the exact same issue with a field that was varchar(3000).  When I moved it to be the last field in the SELECT list, then it worked

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the ODBC driver can't access large text blobs as strings; you need to access them as [chunked BLOB data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681747%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

I advise instead to dump the ODBC connection and [connect using the OLE-DB driver directly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms677227%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). This will let you access that column as if it was just another varchar column.

Answer (score 1):

I just had a similar problem (I think). I converted a varchar field to text. When I did so, I found that the text field seemed to "disappear" from my selected record set. I my case, I discovered that you can reference the text field ONLY ONCE. After that, it seems to disappear. Accordingly, for the text field, I now simply move it into a string variable and then operate on the string. That solved my problem.

John

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem and found the solution here https://web.archive.org/web/20170224013842/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/aspfaqs/ShowFAQ.asp?FAQID=80
  Basically when you open the recordset (not connection.execute) use the options adOpenKeyset (val 1) and adUseClient (val 3), and the text filed should be the last in your field list in strSql
  example: rs.Open strSql, dbConn, adOpenKeyset, adUseClient